# Moving through Detail Pages of Recordset

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

My website allows visitors to search for homes (using PHP and MySql). After the search, they are presented with a list of matches which they can click on to see the detail page for that home. To see the next home, they currently have to click back, then click on the next home in the search results list they want to view.

I would like to make it so that once they have clicked on one home to view the details, they would have a "Next Home" and "Previous Home" link/button to use to navigate the results set without having to go back to the search results page.

I've seen this done, but can't get my head around how to do it. I assume you have to save the recordset from the initial search somewhere, and then recall it on the details page. And you'd have to know that you were looking at the xth home out of Y homes.

Can anyone give me a broad overview of how this would work? Do I save the initial search results in a temp MySQL table and pass that table name to the details page? Or use a session variable to hold the results set? Keep in mind that a visitor could make several different searches during their session.

Any assistance would be most appreciated,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've done this, I've saved the details of the current search in SESSION, and then requeried the database when I've needed to - so you can query it on the detail page to generate a Next and Previous link, and so on. I normally use a SESSION variable called 'parameters', and add the whole of the SQL WHERE statement to it.

If someone's making multiple searches, this will let them make one at a time - subsequent searches will over-write what's already in there. If your users are going to be making multiple searches at the same time using different parameters, you'll need to find a way to differentiate the parameters for each search. You can give each set a unique name by prefixing it with a call to `uniqid`, and you'll then need to make sure you pass the unique identifier to the detail page, so it can work out which set of parameters it needs to run.

Comment: If you save the sql query  how do you know what is the next record?  
e.g. your query is   "select id,* from foo where largetextfield  like   %bar%"   

The the overview page showed 20 records and the user clicks on any record. 

How would you now know what is the next record?

Comment: You're not saving the query per se; you're saving the WHERE clause. When the user clicks to pull up an individual record, say id=3, you need to re-run that search query again, and go through the results to find both the previous and next record, and extract their ID numbers to populate the link. You can do that by using your WHERE clause (to get the same list of records), and then add an extra clause - WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1. You'll need to do it twice (WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) to get the previous record, too.

Comment: You can do it with a single query, but it makes your code more complex; it's up to you whether the cost of two queries outweighs more complicated code. Hopefully this answers your comment - it's been a while since I've had to work with things like this!